# Can someone tell me why this is displaying numbers instead of characters?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, tokenize

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
p {
    visibility: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<pre>Click the button to display the array values after the split.</pre>

<button onclick="myFunction(this)">Try it</button>

<p id="test">"ふ と、目が覚めると 部屋の 中は暗 か"</p>

<script>
function myFunction(p) {
    var str = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML;
    var array = [];
    var array2 = [];
    array.push(str.split(""));
    for (x = 0; x <= str.length; x++) {
        if (array[x] != " ") {
            array2.push(x);
        }
    }
    document.write(array2.toString());
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I feel like the question is stated well but I have to put more content to post this question. So that is the reason for this bottom part. Sorry.

Comment: Because `x` is a number.

Comment: Putting it like this works: array2.push(array[x]); <br> Thanks

Comment: you want to push `array[x]` i assume, not `x` itself ... or use a `foreach` type of construct

Comment: what exactly is the purpose of the variable p? It doesn't look like it's being used for anything.

Comment: I think these two comments have answered the question. Thanks. I don't think I don't see where to put answered though.

Comment: I put <p> there to see how to get the content from html, because I plan on using it later for textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing your loop parameter `x` into the second array, not the character from the first array. You should change the code to:

```
array2.push(array[x]);
```

if your intention is to remove the spaces from the first string.